# Spring: bean with scope=session in jsp

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

In my Spring MVC project I can't access to the parameters of bean with scope=session.Into Http session there is a bean with name "scopedTarget.user" .I want to print, in jsp page, the User's name.Why is it so difficult to access to this parameters?Where am I wrong?

ControllerHome:

```
@Controller
public class ControllerHome {

@Autowired
private User user;

@RequestMapping(value="/",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String welcome(ModelMap model){
    model.addAttribute("utente", user);
    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/add",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String add(@ModelAttribute("utente") User utente,HttpServletRequest request){
    HttpSession session=request.getSession();
    Enumeration<String> list=session.getAttributeNames();
    while(list.hasMoreElements())
        System.out.println(list.nextElement());
    return "redirect:/";
}

}
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<form:form method="get" action="add" modelAttribute="utente">

    <form:input path="nome"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">        
</form:form>
<c:out value="${sessionScope['scopedTarget.user'].nome}"/>

</body>
</html>
```

User.java:

```
public class User implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String nome;

public User(){}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}


}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>config</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>config</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

config-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd">

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="controller"/>

<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<bean class="coreservlets.User" id="user" name="user" scope="session">
    <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: The intend of a `session` scoped bean is different then to be simply used in a jsp page. It is intended to be injected into other beans. If you want to expose a user simply use session attributes for that yourself.

Comment: Your bean name seems to be "user" and not "scopedTarget.user". Use ${user.nome} in JSP instead.

Comment: I tried  both with ${scopedTarget.user} and with ${user.nome} but  I can't access to bean's informations

Comment: Okay. And why are you using "sesionScope" in ${sessionScope['scopedTarget.user'].nome}. Have you used simply ${user.nome}? Also can you change your aop config in config-servlet.xml to <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="true" />

Answer (score 0):

If you add these anotations `@Component` and `@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)` to the POJO you want to be managed in a session, you can then use it in the JSP using the method you spoke of in your question (and Autowire it in your controllers). Make sure of two things though:

1. Don't override the toString(), otherwise it's that result that will be assigned to `${sessionScope['scopedTarget.user']`.
2. Your POJO, in this case User, needs to be "caught" by the Spring's component scanner